# mysql_query SELECT do not give the desired result

Tags: php, mysql

The following code always displays

```
    rows = 0
```

eventhough the table contains Ravi in the field 'to'. Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

```
    <?php
    $response = array();
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if(!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("algopm1",$con);
    //if (isset($_POST['to'])) {
        $to = "Ravi";
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM `events` WHERE to = '$to'");
        if (!empty($result)) {
            if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
                $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                echo $result["to"] + " " + $result["from"];
            } else {
                echo 'rows = 0';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'empty for Ravi';
        }
    //} else {
    //}
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried querying this outside of PHP?

Comment: And try to use or die(mysql_error());

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: @jperovic I do not understand what you telling because I am new to this mysql. Can you please explain how to do it?

Comment: @nlsbshtr I think the blank you are mentioning is optional because it is producing same result.

Comment: @njk I went through mysql_* functions before trying this. But I feel that eventhough it is depreceated it should work for testing purpose and it is not working.

Comment: @user2015988 check if your PHP version is greater than 5.5. If that is the case your query won't work even for testing purposes.

Comment: @Mr.Radical my PHP version: 5.3.9 and MySQL version: 5.5.20

Comment: @user2015988 have you tried my answer below?

Comment: @njk I read the MySQLi* functions and got a proper working code. Thanks for suggesting alternate methods.

Comment: @user2015988 I have added a more detailed answer. You should be able to pinpoint the error easily ;)

Comment: @user2015988 is your question solved?

Comment: @Mr.Radical My question is solved by using the newer version of MySQL, i.e., mysqli_* functions.

Comment: @user2015988 Great to hear that your question is solved. Please accept and / or upvote one of the answers below if you think they have contributed to you solving your question.

Comment: @Mr.Radical I was about to ask today where can I post my solution because the moment I clicked the button "Answer your question", it alerted me something. Can I use the same button to post the solution?

Comment: @Mr.Radical Anyway, I will post my answer. If it is not a proper method to post solutions or if there is some other better method in solving the question, please let me know.

Comment: @user2015988 you can answer your own question if you want to. Just like if you are a total stranger. Scoll down the page, there you will find a button with "add another answer".  However, be so kind to up vote or accept the answer form others if you think they may have contributed to you solving this question. Good luck with you project.

Comment: @user2015988 I see you have posted an answer. Now you can click on accept next to your question. B.T.W. I read your code I would advice you to protect you project against SQL injection via the POST variables.

Comment: @Mr.Radical I do not know anything about the SQL injections till now. I thank you for mentioning it. I will read about it. And when I try to upvote I get "Vote up requires 15 reputions." I do not have any idea about it.

Comment: @user2015988 if you accept you own answer you reputation will probably move up. W.R.T. sql injection you could first start with storing all the $_POST variables inside new variables with a function like htmlentities() to sanitize the inputed data. E.g. `$to = htmlentities($_POST['to'])`. Then use the variable $to to in the rest of your code. There a lot of ways to check if the inputed data is valid. For example you could also check if a number value is inserted.

Answer (score 6):

`to` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, if you want to use it you must encase it in backticks:

```
.... WHERE `to` = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not look at your code but I recommend looking at

```
http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php
```

this before you continue to use mysql and not mysqli. It isn't that different but mysqli seems to have a wrapper over mysql and uses the "->" to instantiate new classes for a connection. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$response = array();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("algopm1",$con);
//if (isset($_POST['to'])) {
    $to = "Ravi";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM `events` WHERE `to` = '$to'");
    if (!empty($result)) {
        if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            echo $row["to"] + " " + $row["from"];
        } else {
            echo 'rows = 0';
        }
    } else {
        echo "empty for $to";
    }
//} else {
//}
?>
```

MYSQLI version + some adjustments:

```
<?PHP
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database="algopm1";



    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    IF (!$link){
        echo ("Unable to connect to database!");
    }
    ELSE {
    $query = "SELECT *FROM `events` WHERE `to` = '$to'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
     if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    echo $row["to"]. "+". $row["from"];
    }
     }
     ELSE {
         echo 'rows = 0';
     }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

I would like to credit @njk and @Wezy for their contribution with regard to the reserved word to in mysql. The WHILE loop is not necessary if the table events can only contain one "to" in this case "Ravi". I suspect that the number of events can be greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

@Wezy has a point but let's do the troubleshooting:

As @JonathanRomer in his comment suggested, do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM `events` WHERE `to` = '$to'") or die(mysql_error());
```

What does it say? Does it fail at all?

*Or*, just before `mysql_query` do:

```
die("SELECT *FROM `events` WHERE `to` = '$to'");
```

this will print faulty query being executed. Next, fire up `mysql` console or `PHPMyAdmin` and try executing this query manually.

Again, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my main purpose was to encode this message and receive it on a mobile device by using JSON. This is the full code. For normal checking purpose, instead of using json_encode(*), the values can be displayed individually. This is the solution I got and it is working perfectly for receiving the data in an android app on which I am working.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database="algopm1";
$response = array();

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = mysqli_connect_error();
    echo json_encode($response);
}

if(isset($_POST['to'])) {
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $query = "SELECT *FROM `events` WHERE `to` = '$to'";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $i = 0;
        if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($rowto, $rowfrom, $rowevent);
            $response["events"] = array();
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $events = array();
                $events["to"] = $rowto;
                $events["from"] = $rowfrom;
                $events["event"] = $rowevent;
                array_push($response["events"], $events);
            }
            $response["success"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No events found";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required fields are missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```